# Working with wordpress in ssh. How do I add pages and they reflect my files in command line?

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh

So I accessed my company wordpress files through ssh on my command line and I have them pulled up and need to make a few landing pages. Im in QA. How do I create new pages? So i tried to create a new page in my WP admin panel but the new page's id isnt showing up in my terminal with the rest of the files. I know I am missing a step and maybe you need more information from me but any advice? And I am trying to get it in my terminal because I need to just make a landing page and I dont want to build it inside my admin panel I dont know how the previous guy did the current templates.

Comment: Pages done in wp dashboard are in DB, to render wp uses files in theme. Which one is selected - answers are in https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically changes to Wordpress are done within the admin section through a GUI. This is because Wordpress creates pages and posts by writing to the database. If you are dead set on using command line, however, I would suggest taking a look at [WP-CLI](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli). It is an interface library that allows you to do most Wordpress things without a browser.

Comment: This may *be* the correct approach, but keep in mind that `WP-cli` requires root privileges to run (the OP may not have such on the web server): `chmod +x wp-cli.phar` and 
`sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/bin/wp`. However, +1 for this utility, I did't know that there is such nice tool.

Comment: So you would suggest always building pages with the admin panel? Even if we have a bunch of differently formatted landing pages for different campaigns?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't always suggest it — it's just how Wordpress is typically used. If you feel that command line would be a better solution than I would trust your judgement. What I would probably do in that situation, though, is create several page templates — one for each campaign. You can then assign those page templates to individual page URLs